# Byte to "Bit"array

Tags: java, byte, bit, primitive

A byte is the smallest numeric datatype java offers but yesterday I came in contact with bytestreams for the first time and at the beginning of every package a marker byte is send which gives further instructions on how to handle the package. Every bit of the byte has a specific meaning so I am in need to entangle the byte into it's 8 bits.

You probably could convert the byte to a boolean array or create a switch for every case but that can't certainly be the best practice.

How is this possible in java why are there no bit datatypes in java?

Comment: There are boolean and BitSet types.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because there is no bit data type that exists on the physical computer. The smallest allotment you can allocate on most modern computers is a byte which is also known as an octet or 8 bits. When you display a single bit you are really just pulling that first bit out of the byte with arithmetic and adding it to a new byte which still is using an 8 bit space. If you want to put bit data inside of a byte you can but it will be stored as a at least a single byte no matter what programming language you use.

Comment: thank you this sounds reasonable. So bitwise operation using bytes would be the way to go?

Comment: @user3394605 exactly, and if you put all your bytes in an array you will have a nice compact location in memory with all your bits. Because remember the way the JVM works is a byte still uses as much space as an int. The only way you can benefit by the size difference is by putting your bytes in an array.

Answer (score 6):

You could load the byte into a BitSet. This abstraction hides the gory details of manipulating single bits.

```
import java.util.BitSet;

public class Bits {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        byte[] b = new byte[]{10};
        BitSet bitset = BitSet.valueOf(b);
        System.out.println("Length of bitset = " + bitset.length());
        for (int i=0; i<bitset.length(); ++i) {
            System.out.println("bit " + i + ": " + bitset.get(i));
        }
    }
}

$ java Bits
Length of bitset = 4
bit 0: false
bit 1: true
bit 2: false
bit 3: true
```

You can ask for any bit, but the length tells you that all the bits past `length() - 1` are set to `0` (false):

```
System.out.println("bit 75: " + bitset.get(75));

bit 75: false
```

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at java.util.BitSet.
You might use it to interpret the byte read and can use the get method to check whether a specific bit is set like this:

```
byte b = stream.read();
final BitSet bitSet = BitSet.valueOf(new byte[]{b});
if (bitSet.get(2)) {
    state.activateComponentA();
} else {
    state.deactivateComponentA();
}
state.setFeatureBTo(bitSet.get(1));
```

On the other hand, you can create your own bitmask easily and convert it to a byte array (or just byte) afterwards:

```
final BitSet output = BitSet.valueOf(ByteBuffer.allocate(1));
output.set(3, state.isComponentXActivated());
if (state.isY){
    output.set(4);
}
final byte w = output.toByteArray()[0];
```

Comment: Mind to elaborate that a bit?

Comment: jas pretty much elaborated how to use it. Since it was unclear to me what the author of the question was trying to do, I just wanted to make him aware of the BitSet class. It can be used to wrap the bytes in question and provides easy get/set actions for positional access of specific bits.

Comment: better to add this to your answer using the edit button. In general, answers should be self-contained, as other answers or comments may be deleted or sth like that. Saw your answer while reviewing low quality posts. Shortness is one criterion. ;)

Answer (score 2):

`How is this possible in java why are there no bit datatypes in java?`

There are no bit data types in *most* languages. And most CPU instruction sets have few (if any) instructions dedicated to adressing single bits. You can think of the lack of these as a trade-off between (language or CPU) complexity and need.

Manipulating a *single* bit can be though of as a special case of manipulating *multiple* bits; and languages as well as CPU's are equipped for the latter.

Very common operations like testing, setting, clearing, inverting as well as exclusive or are all supported on the integer primitive types (byte, short/char, int, long), operating on all bits of the type at once. By chosing the parameters appropiately you can select which bits to operate on.

If you think about it, a byte array *is* a bit array where the bits are grouped in packages of 8. Adressing a single bit in the array is relatively simple using logical operators (AND `&`, OR `|`, XOR `^` and NOT `~`).

For example, testing if bit N is set in a byte can be done using a logical AND with a mask where only the bit to be tested is set:

```
public boolean testBit(byte b, int n) {
    int mask = 1 << n; // equivalent of 2 to the nth power
    return (b & mask) != 0;
}
```

Extending this to a byte array is no magic either, each byte consists of 8 bits, so the byte index is simply the bit number divided by 8, and the bit number inside that byte is the remainder (modulo 8):

```
public boolean testBit(byte[] array, int n) {
    int index = n >>> 3; // divide by 8
    int mask = 1 << (n & 7); // n modulo 8
    return (array[index] & mask) != 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a sample, I hope useful for you!

```
DatagramSocket socket = new DatagramSocket(6160, InetAddress.getByName("0.0.0.0"));
socket.setBroadcast(true);
while (true) {
    byte[] recvBuf = new byte[26];
    DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(recvBuf, recvBuf.length);
    socket.receive(packet);
    String bitArray = toBitArray(recvBuf);
    System.out.println(Integer.parseInt(bitArray.substring(0, 8), 2)); // convert first byte binary to decimal
    System.out.println(Integer.parseInt(bitArray.substring(8, 16), 2)); // convert second byte binary to decimal
}
```

```
public static String toBitArray(byte[] byteArray) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0; i < byteArray.length; i++) {
            sb.append(String.format("%8s", Integer.toBinaryString(byteArray[i] & 0xFF)).replace(' ', '0'));
        }
        return sb.toString();
}
```